# How to implement full text search in MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, full-text-search

I've a working search engine in MVC.

**/View/Content/Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Example.Models.Content>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Content", FormMethod.Get))
 {
  @Html.TextBox("keyword0")
 }

@foreach (var item in Model)
 {
    @Html.DisplayFor(item.article_title)
 }
```

**/Controllers/ContentController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Example.Models;

namespace Example.Controllers
{
    public class ContentController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(string keyword0)
        {
            return View(db.Content.Where(x => x.article_title.Contains(keyword0)).ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

Searching returns results from the article_title column in SQL that matches the keyword being used. If I type **foo** into search, any record in SQL where the article_title contains foo is returned.

I am attempting to enhance the search engine with full text capabilities. I've converted the article_title column in SQL to be a full text index. In SQL Server Management Studio, a full text search works as expected, only displaying records that contain both keywords foo and bar.

```
select * from table_name where contains (article_title, 'foo and bar')
```

In my MVC application, if I enter **foo bar** into search, no records are displayed. Because the URL ends with search=foo+bar, no records are displayed, as there are no records in SQL where the article_title contains **foo+bar**. I've updated my /Controllers/ContentController.cs to search with both keyword0 and keyword1.

```
return View(db.Content.Where(x => x.article_title.Contains(keyword0) && x.article_title.Contains(keyword1)).ToList());
```

If I manually adjust the URL to be www.example.com/?keyword0=foo&keyword1=bar, the search works properly, and only records that contain both foo and bar are displayed.

Where I am challenged is passing foo and bar from the @HTML.TextFor in the View to the *public ActionResult Index()* in the Controller, and then splitting foo and bar, so that keyword0 contains foo and keyword1 contains bar.

The idea I have come up with is to pass the text entered in the @Html.TextBox from the View to the Controller in a variable named **search**. The Controller will then retrieve this text by adding **string search** to the public ActionResult.

```
public ActionResult Index(string search)
{
    return View(db.Content.Where(x => x.article_title.Contains(keyword0) && x.article_title.Contains(keyword1)).ToList());
}
```

If I publish the application now, there are no errors. However, the text in the *string search* variable is not being passed to keyword0 or keyword1. My next idea is to split the text in the *string search* variable, and then create variables keyword0 and keyword1.

```
public ActionResult Index(string search)
{
    string[] keywords = search.Split(' ');
    string keyword0 = keywords[0];
    string keyword1 = keywords[1];
    return View(db.Content.Where(x => x.article_title.Contains(keyword0) && x.article_title.Contains(keyword1)).ToList());
}
```

When I add the code to split the search variable to my Controller, the web browser produces error **An error occurred while processing your request**. I am not sure how to split the search variable and then to create variables keyword0 and keyword1 without producing **An error occurred while processing your request**.

Comment: You definitely have to check that your `search` argument is not null and `keywords[0]`, `keywords[1]` are not null.

Comment: @raderick Thank you very much for sharing the tip to ensure that my search argument is not null and that keyword[0] and keyword[1] are not null. If I am not mistaken, I am fairly certain that my search agrument is not null, because when I don't include string[] keywords = search.Split(' '); in the controller, the text is being passed from the controller to the view in the string search. It is only when adding string[] keywords = search.Split(' '); to the controller that "An error occurred while processing your request" is displayed. I really appreciate the tip you have shared.

Comment: you definitely should do some defensive code here, because splitting search string might give you array of any size, depending on number of spaces, so you need to adapt your code to that change - make a method that takes an array of string and generates an Expression, that you can pass to `db.Context.Where(YourExpression)`.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting that I make a method that takes an array of a string and generates an expression to pass to the DB. I will work on this. Thank you very much.